# Align text near "textarea"

Tags: html, css

I have a textarea box and I need it one half the page. After it, I need to put some more text and another textarea.

This is what I have for now:

```
<p>Supervisory responsability <span style="color:red">*</span>
        <input type="radio" name="tip" value="Supervision"
        checked="checked" style="margin-left:15px"/> Supervision
        <input type="radio" name="tip" value="Direction"
        checked="checked"/>Direction
        <input type="radio" name="tip" value="None" />
        None
        <br/>
        <textarea cols="75%" rows="3" style="margin-left:153px"></textarea>
            <div id="one">
                <p>Total number of subordinates 
                    <textarea cols="75%" rows="1"></textarea></p>
            </div>
</p>
```

So the "total number of subordinates" should be on the right top corner of the textarea.

image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CUAi.jpg

Any clue how can I do that with both HTML and CSS?

Comment: Do you have a layout image/psd that you can show to better explain what you want to achieve?

Comment: Sure. http://i.imgur.com/oAR3GkO.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do You have some kind of reference? An Image or something? through which it is more easy for us to understand what you wanna do??

Comment: added a link to my original post :)

Comment: almost there, thank you :D I'll have to readjust the next textarea, but yes, it's there :) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

There would be better

```
<div id="one">
   <p style="width: 50%; float: left; ">Total number of subordinates</p>
   <textarea style="width: 50%; float: right; " rows="1"></textarea>
</div>
```

or (because using of textarea seems be useless)

```
<div id="one">
   <p style="width: 50%; float: left;">Total number of subordinates</p>
   <input type="text" style="width: 50%; float: right;">
</div>
```

Comment: it messed with the layout besides it.

Comment: Oh, pardon ... I missed you have to have text cursor on that positon in textarea, at first time. Use text-align: right (but I am not sure if it will have correct effect on textarea). But really, if you need to write only number, use <input type="text"> with CSS text-align: right;